# SQL Multiple Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have my query almost correct. The only thing I can't get is that  I need to pull the row with the most recent Date change and its pull all row for each stock number. What am I doing wrong!

[The highlighted item should be the results I need.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORE49.png)

```
SELECT DISTINCT  ivp.VendorStockNumber, i.StockNumber, i.StockDescription, 
                 ivp.PackDescription, ib.BrandName, 
                 MAX(ich.NewPackCost) as Cost, 
                 MAX(ich.ModifiedDate) as DateChanged
FROM InvVendors iv, InvVendorProducts ivp, InvBrands ib, InvItems i, 
InvCostPackSizeHistory ich, InvSiteTypesItems ist, 
InvSiteTypesItemsVendorProducts itp
WHERE i.InvItemID = ivp.InvItemID
AND iv.InvVendorID = ivp.InvVendorID 
AND ib.InvBrandID = ivp.InvBrandID
AND ist.InvSiteTypesItemID = ich.InvSiteTypesItemID
AND ist.InvSiteTypesItemID = itp.InvSiteTypesItemID
AND ivp.InvVendorProductID = itp.InvVendorProductID
AND i.InvItemID = ist.InvItemID
AND iv.VendorNumber = '5'
AND ivp.VendorStockNumber <> ''
AND ich.NewPackCost <> ich.OldPackCost
AND itp.Preferred = '1'
GROUP BY  ivp.VendorStockNumber, i.StockNumber, i.StockDescription, 
          ivp.PackDescription, ib.BrandName, ich.NewPackCost
ORDER BY i.StockNumber ASC, DateChanged DESC
```

Comment: You should start switching to 'modern' `join..on` syntax, it's the ansi standard for 30-odd years!

Comment: You rarely never combine SELECT DISTINCT with GROUP BY.

Comment: Remove ich.NewPackCost from GROUP BY. (You typically GROUP BY the columns you select, except those who are arguments to set functions.)

Comment: "Almost correct" and not a `JOIN` in site.  No where close to being correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` partition by `VendorStockNumber` like following.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T.VendorStockNumber ORDER BY T.DateChanged DESC) RN 
    FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT  ivp.VendorStockNumber, i.StockNumber, i.StockDescription, 
        ivp.PackDescription, ib.BrandName, MAX(ich.NewPackCost) as Cost, MAX 
        (ich.ModifiedDate) as DateChanged
        FROM InvVendors iv, InvVendorProducts ivp, InvBrands ib, InvItems i, 
        InvCostPackSizeHistory ich, InvSiteTypesItems ist, 
        InvSiteTypesItemsVendorProducts itp
        WHERE i.InvItemID = ivp.InvItemID
        AND iv.InvVendorID = ivp.InvVendorID 
        AND ib.InvBrandID = ivp.InvBrandID
        AND ist.InvSiteTypesItemID = ich.InvSiteTypesItemID
        AND ist.InvSiteTypesItemID = itp.InvSiteTypesItemID
        AND ivp.InvVendorProductID = itp.InvVendorProductID
        AND i.InvItemID = ist.InvItemID
        AND iv.VendorNumber = '5'
        AND ivp.VendorStockNumber <> ''
        AND ich.NewPackCost <> ich.OldPackCost
        AND itp.Preferred = '1'
        GROUP BY  ivp.VendorStockNumber, i.StockNumber, i.StockDescription, 
        ivp.PackDescription, ib.BrandName, ich.NewPackCost
    )T


) T1
WHERE RN=1
ORDER BY StockNumber ASC, DateChanged DESC
```

Comment: I get an error : Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.

Comment: error message: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Column 'InvCostPackSizeHistory.ModifiedDate' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Comment: Can you try now, I tried wrapping your query inside a table and applying the rownumber logic

Comment: I get an invalid column name on line 3 'ModifiedDate'

Comment: change ORDER BY T.ModifiedDate DESC  to ORDER BY T.DateChanged DESC

Comment: PSK - I fixed and it runs I had to change ModifiedDate to its alias DateChanged

Comment: I get OP is happy but that original query still has some funky stuff.  If you need a group by and a distinct there is typically a problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT  ivp.VendorStockNumber, i.StockNumber, i.StockDescription, 
ivp.PackDescription, ib.BrandName, MAX(ich.NewPackCost) as Cost, MAX 
(ich.ModifiedDate) as DateChanged
FROM InvVendors iv, InvVendorProducts ivp, InvBrands ib, InvItems i, 
InvCostPackSizeHistory ich, InvSiteTypesItems ist, 
InvSiteTypesItemsVendorProducts itp
WHERE i.InvItemID = ivp.InvItemID
AND iv.InvVendorID = ivp.InvVendorID 
AND ib.InvBrandID = ivp.InvBrandID
AND ist.InvSiteTypesItemID = ich.InvSiteTypesItemID
AND ist.InvSiteTypesItemID = itp.InvSiteTypesItemID
AND ivp.InvVendorProductID = itp.InvVendorProductID
AND i.InvItemID = ist.InvItemID
AND iv.VendorNumber = '5'
AND ivp.VendorStockNumber <> ''
AND ich.NewPackCost <> ich.OldPackCost
AND itp.Preferred = '1'
GROUP BY  ivp.VendorStockNumber, i.StockNumber, i.StockDescription, 
ivp.PackDescription, ib.BrandName, ich.NewPackCost
ORDER BY  DateChanged DESC,i.StockNumber ASC
```

Comment: What did you change, and why did that fix the problem?

Comment: I don't know as I'm not the OP. But anyway, a good answer would explain why it changed what it changed, instead of just dumping code that superficially looks exactly the same.

Comment: Your fix is to change the order by ?

Answer (score 0):

That query has some serious problems.  `MAX(ich.NewPackCost)` when `ich.NewPackCost` is in the `group by` makes no sense.

I typically will not answer old style joins

You need the rows with rn = 1 from the query below

```
SELECT DISTINCT  ivp.VendorStockNumber, i.StockNumber, i.StockDescription, 
                 ivp.PackDescription, ib.BrandName, 
                 ich.NewPackCost as Cost, 
                 ich.ModifiedDate as DateChanged,
                 row_number() over (partition by ivp.VendorStockNumber order by DateChanged desc) as rn 
FROM InvVendors iv, InvVendorProducts ivp, InvBrands ib, InvItems i, 
InvCostPackSizeHistory ich, InvSiteTypesItems ist, 
InvSiteTypesItemsVendorProducts itp
WHERE i.InvItemID = ivp.InvItemID
AND iv.InvVendorID = ivp.InvVendorID 
AND ib.InvBrandID = ivp.InvBrandID
AND ist.InvSiteTypesItemID = ich.InvSiteTypesItemID
AND ist.InvSiteTypesItemID = itp.InvSiteTypesItemID
AND ivp.InvVendorProductID = itp.InvVendorProductID
AND i.InvItemID = ist.InvItemID
AND iv.VendorNumber = '5'
AND ivp.VendorStockNumber <> ''
AND ich.NewPackCost <> ich.OldPackCost
AND itp.Preferred = '1'
ORDER BY i.StockNumber ASC, DateChanged DESC
```

Comment: I get an error a:Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Invalid column name 'DateChanged'.

Comment: @GNell Apply yourself.  There is an extra )